# Extract geometry from feature not working?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

This works:

(with geometry being a Polygon and sent3 an ImageCollection):

```
var image = sent3.filterBounds(roi).first();
var mask = image.select("Oa07_radiance").mask().rename('mask');
var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().multiply(mask).rename('area');

var sumDictionarypolygon1 = mask.addBands(area).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 300,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print('sum for pol 1 mask, scale=300', sumDictionarypolygon1);
```

While this does not (roi being a Feature containing a geometry)

```
var rois = ee.FeatureCollection("users/guillaumh/embalsescba"),
    sent3 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI");
var roi = rois.toList(99).get(26);
print(roi);

var image = sent3.filterBounds(roi).first();
var mask = image.select("Oa07_radiance").mask().rename('mask');
var area = ee.Image.pixelArea().multiply(mask).rename('area');

var sumDictionarypolygon1 = mask.addBands(area).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: ee.Geometry(roi),
  scale: 300,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print('sum for pol 1 mask, scale=300', sumDictionarypolygon1);
```

The error is:

```
Dictionary (Error)
Feature, argument 'geometry': Invalid type. Expected type: Geometry. Actual type: Feature.
```

Why cannot I extract the geometry from the feature? It seems ee.Geometry(  ) does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of `ee.Geometry(roi)` (which in this case is essentially "assume this is already a `Geometry`", which it isn't), you need to use `ee.Feature(roi).geometry()`, which returns the geometry of the feature.

Second, you modified your call to `reduceRegion` but you also wrote `filterBounds(roi)`, which also needs a Geometry rather than a Feature.

Therefore, try this:

```
var roi = ee.Feature(rois.toList(99).get(26)).geometry();
```

Then both of the places you use `roi` will work.

Comment: I also tried this but I'm getting the error `roi.geometry is not a function`. Also tried with `ee.Feature(roi).geometry()` and got the error: `Dictionary (Error)
Feature, argument 'geometry': Invalid type. Expected type: Geometry. Actual type: Feature.`

Comment: @gh_ Whoops, you're right, it won't work without a cast … not sure why it isn't working _with_ a cast. Sorry. But if possible, you should avoid converting your (I assume) feature collection to a list — it's inefficient. Use an 'eq' filter instead of looking for a specific index.

Comment: @gh_ I can't reproduce the error. Could you please edit your question so that it contains complete code to reproduce the error (not having any undefined variables like `rois`)? You can get the code for drawn features in the Code Editor by clicking on the little button to the right of "Imports". Or a "Get Link" link will also do, but it would be good to have the question edited too.

Comment: indeed that should be more helpful, done!

Comment: @gh_ I found the problem — your `filterBounds` also needed a geometry rather than a feature. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you! still need to get used to the API.